# Displaying a message dialogbox in a specified table cell in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have created a table using HTML, XML and XLST. I am creating a table using a for-each loop which inserts the data from the xml file.

Once the table is filled with data, I would like every cell that is clicked to display dialogue message box.

**Code for XML file:**

```
<person>
    <title>Abraham</title>
    <slota>Johns</slota>
    <slotb>22</slotb>
    <slotc>male</slotc>
    <slotd>ave road</slotd>
    <slote>0384847</slote>
    <slotf>shdh@hot.com</slotf>
    <slotg>UK</slotg>
  </person>
```

Above is the code with all the data needed to be inserted into the table.

**XSLT Code:**

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="DarkGray" >Employee</th>
          <th id="cell1" bgcolor="DarkGray">name</th>
          <th id="cell2" bgcolor="DarkGray">surname</th>
           <th id="cell3" bgcolor="DarkGray">age</th>
          <th id="cell4" bgcolor="DarkGray">gender</th>
          <th id="cell5" bgcolor="DarkGray">address</th>
           <th id="cell6" bgcolor="DarkGray">phone</th>
          <th  id="cell7" bgcolor="DarkGray">country</th>

        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="persons">
        <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="slota" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="slotb" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="slotc" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="slotd" /></td>
            td><xsl:value-of select="slote" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="slotf" /></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="slotg" /></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
```

Above is the code for XSL file creating the table and inserting data using the `for-each` loop.

I have created a function that displays a dialog message box using JavaScript and here the code below:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {

      alert ("I am an alert box");
      }
      </script>
```

When I place this function in a table cell that I would it to be triggers it for example:

```
<td onclick="myFunction()"><xsl:value-of select="slota" /></td>.
```

The function applies to each and every table cell in that row.

Is there a way I can apply this function to one specific row?
Or, is it because I am using a `for-each` loop to create the table?

Comment: *"Is there a way i can apply this function to one specific row?"* Your question is not clear: in your example, the XML input has only one row. It *is* possible to apply the `onclick` attribute to cells of a specific row only - but how do you identify that row?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Jquery for this sort of thing. Jquery is a javascript framework.

You can create a [click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for table cells within a particular table. An example of this:

```
$('table tr td').click(function()
{
    alert('I am an alert box');
});
```

It is also worth noting that you can apply logic to the selector of this event to only select cells with a particular class or attribute value for instance. 'table tr td' Is the selector. If you wanted to select only cells with a class of 'foo' you would write: 'table tr td.foo'.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying.  lets say i want the selector to select a  column with the heading "name" and the cell "Abraham" will i have to put it like:                                                               "table tr td.abraham"?

Comment: table tr td.abraham will select any td element with the class 'abraham'. It would not factor in a header as they are not linked. What you would need to do is to say (for each column) what type it is. So on the 2nd column add a class for each cell, "name". What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is, is when a cell is clicked, I want it to display a dialog message box. I want different cells to display different messages , so I am trying to select particular cells to do this. I hope this makes sense.. thank you for your time.

Comment: The easiest way (if I understand you correctly) (you want to display a message based on it's column header). You should define each cell by a class name. There are more code efficient ways of doing this (by index for instance) but this is the easiest for you.

Comment: So simply put... <td class="name"> Then use my click event above to select based on that class name.

Comment: okay, im my case i've done: $('table tr td.ppl').click(function()
{
    alert('I am an alert box');
});                                                                          and then <td  class="ppl"align="center" ><xsl:value-of select="slota" /></td>............. still not working :( sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Have you included jquery into your page?